# Get property name by attribute value

Tags: c#, attributes

Good day, How can I get class's property name, if I have custom attribute value for that property? and custom attribute name of course.

Comment: Please explain more, your question is not very clear as-is and will likely be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Get property name by custom attribute:**

```
    public static string[] GetPropertyNameByCustomAttribute
      <ClassToAnalyse, AttributeTypeToFind>
      (
       Func<AttributeTypeToFind, bool> attributePredicate
      )
      where AttributeTypeToFind : Attribute
    {  
      if (attributePredicate == null)
      {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("attributePredicate");
      }
      else
      {
        List<string> propertyNames = new List<string>();

        foreach 
        (
          PropertyInfo propertyInfo in typeof(ClassToAnalyse).GetProperties()
        )
        {
          if
          (
            propertyInfo.GetCustomAttributes
            (
              typeof(AttributeTypeToFind), true
            ).Any
            (
              currentAttribute =>                  
              attributePredicate((AttributeTypeToFind)currentAttribute)
            )
          )
          {
            propertyNames.Add(propertyInfo.Name);
          }
        }  

        return propertyNames.ToArray();
      }
    }
```

**Test fixtures:**

```
public class FooAttribute : Attribute
{
  public String Description { get; set; }
}

class FooClass
{
  private int fooProperty = 42;

  [Foo(Description="Foo attribute description")]
  public int FooProperty
  {
    get
    {
      return this.fooProperty;
    }
  }

}
```

**Test cases:**

```
// It will return "FooProperty"
GetPropertyNameByCustomAttribute<FooClass, FooAttribute>
( 
  attribute => attribute.Description == "Foo attribute description"
);


// It will return an empty array
GetPropertyNameByCustomAttribute<FooClass, FooAttribute>
( 
  attribute => attribute.Description == "Bar attribute description"
);
```

Comment: What does this have to do with attributes? Granted the question isn't clear, but this doesn't even have the word "attribute" in the answer.

Comment: Not sure why this is being downvoted. My take on the question is that the OP is asking about how to retrieve a list of invokable properties for a given object. Taking into account the lack of information in the question this answer seems about right.

Comment: Clearly I'have understood that he wants to know how to use Reflection API because of other related questions I heard about the reflection API, I know that for someone who doesn't know this API, it's very difficult to explain his intent.

Comment: You should get the attributes for the properties: propertyInfo.Attributes, this would help answer the question.  or for custom attributes: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a4a92379.aspx